# How to swap column 1 column 2 values based condition if column 1 value is less than column 2 then I want to swap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

initially my dataframe like this

```
    Column1 Column2
0   A   B
1   D   F
2   C   H
3   NaN J
4   T   G
5   Z   True
6   S   Y
7   G   V
8   R   Y
9   T   X
```

i am replacing Nan and True values with A

```
df.replace([np.nan,True],'A',inplace=True)
```

now my dataframe like this

```
    Column1 Column2
0   A   B
1   D   F
2   C   H
3   A   J
4   T   G
5   Z   A
6   S   Y
7   G   V
8   R   Y
9   T   X
```

now i am comapring column 1 values with column 2 if column 1 values smaller than column 2 i want to swap column 2 values in column 1 and column 1 values with column 2 if column 1 values bigger than column 2 no swapping

```
df.Column1, df.Column2 = np.where(str(df.Column1) < str(df.Column2), [df.Column2, df.Column1], [df.Column1, df.Column2])
```

now my dataframe like this

```
Column1 Column2
0   B   A
1   F   D
2   H   C
3   J   A
4   G   T
5   A   Z
6   Y   S
7   V   G
8   Y   R
9   X   T
```

4th and 5th rows are not swapped here how to fix this issue

Comment: I believe you just have typo/logic issue with `str(df.Column1) < str(df.Column2)`. You don't want to convert a column to a String because you're only going to get a single True or False value since you're comparing the String representation of one series compared to the String representation of another rather than each value in the Series. `df.Column1, df.Column2 = np.where(df.Column1 < df.Column2, [df.Column2, df.Column1], [df.Column1, df.Column2])` works.

Comment: You might have also meant `df.Column1.astype(str) < df.Column2.astype(str)`

Answer (score 1):

You could sort each row of the underlying numpy array in-place:

```
df

  Column1 Column2
0       B       A
1       F       D
2       H       C
3       J       A
4       G       T
5       A       Z
6       Y       S
7       V       G
8       Y       R
9       X       T

# numpy.ndarray.sort sorts in-place
df.values.sort(axis=1)

df

  Column1 Column2
0       A       B
1       D       F
2       C       H
3       A       J
4       G       T
5       A       Z
6       S       Y
7       G       V
8       R       Y
9       T       X
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this one-liner with `max` and `min`:

```
>>> df['Column1'], df['Column2'] = df.max(1), df.min(1)
>>> df
  Column1 Column2
0       B       A
1       F       D
2       H       C
3       J       A
4       T       G
5       Z       A
6       Y       S
7       V       G
8       Y       R
9       X       T
>>>
```